# Why is a self:: scope required in this situation

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have a simple base class

```
class base {
  function do_something() {
    $result = helper_function();
  return $result;
}

private function helper_function() {
    return 10;
  }

}
```

Then I have a main class which inherits from it.

```
class my_class extends base {
  function __construct() {
    echo parent::do_something();
  }
}
```

In order for this to work I need to specify `parent::do_something()` in `my_class`. I get this and it makes sense. However, this code will throw an error. In order for it to work I must specify:

```
$result = self::helper_function();
```

To me this doesn't make any sense. Since it is having me modify the base class which would work on its own if it wasn't inherited. Seems contradictory to the model of inheritance.

Maybe I'm just doing it wrong. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `self::` prefix usually means that you are calling a parent static method. If this function is not declared in the same class but in a class from which you inherit that method then you should use `parent::`. Usually function not specific declared as `static` are not to consider static. If you are calling a normal method you should use `$this->` instead.

The main difference between static and normal method is that:

- Static method can be called even without istanciating the class
- Normal method must be called after and object of that class is created

so that:

```
class foo {
    public function normal() {}
    public static function static() {}
}

foo::static(); // works
foo::normal() // don't work
$foo = new foo();
$foo->normal(); // works
```

References:

- [Static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)
- [Classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$this->helper_function()`.
It's a method of the class so you have to call it using `$this`. With `self::` you call it statically which you shouldn't do unless a function is declared as `static`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
  function __construct() {
    echo $this->do_something();
  }
```

`$this` refers to this class and any of the public or protected options of the parent